# Error converting string to date: does not match format '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in a string format: "Wed, 26 Apr 2017 12:39:28 GMT" and need to convert to datetime.

To do the conversion I am using datetime.strptime

Ex:

```
datetime.strptime ("Wed, 26 Apr 2017 12:39:28 GMT", '% b% d% Y% I:% M% p')
```

However, the error:
ValueError: time data 'Wed, 26 Apr 2017 12:39:57 GMT' does not match format '% b% d% Y% I:% M% p'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If string cannot be parsed according to format, or if it has excess data after parsing, `ValueError` is raised. You should remove the redundant spaces and modify the directive which would be used to parse the given string.

you can try this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> ds="Wed, 26 Apr 2017 12:39:28 GMT"
>>>
>>> datetime.strptime (ds, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 26, 12, 39, 28)
```

See more details from [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, the string doesn't match the format. Try this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed, 26 Apr 2017 12:39:28 GMT', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```